# Automating tinymce with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, tinymce, selenium-webdriver, wysiwyg

I am having trouble writing on tinymce version 3.5.8.

```
def self.content(text)
  # to write on a WYSIWYG editor write on the iframe
  $driver.switch_to.frame('WikiRevision_content_ifr')
  $driver.find_element(:id, 'tinymce').send_keys text
  $driver.switch_to.default_content
  self
end
```

No content appears on my WYSIWYG editor.  No errors are raised.
Trying to write on tinymce with ruby 2.0 and selenium-webdriver 2.39

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/) is an article you might find useful - "[Test WYSIWYG editors using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/01/31/test-wysiwyg-editors-using-selenium-webdriver/)"

For your issue, few things you can try. (Assume your frame switching is done correctly, show your HTML if you need help.)

- Send keys to body (not sure what your `id=tinymce` is without knowing HTML)

```ruby
$driver.switch_to.frame('WikiRevision_content_ifr')
$driver.find_element(:css, 'body').send_keys text
```

- Set innerHTML

```ruby
$driver.switch_to.frame('WikiRevision_content_ifr')
$driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'arguments[1]'", $driver.find_element(:css => 'body'), text)
```

- Use TinyMCE's native JS

```ruby
$driver.execute_script("tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('arguments[0]')", text)
```

Comment: @Zach: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?